# Is it ok to change a value that is used in compareTo in a TreeSet?

Tags: java, treeset

I have this simple Pojo:

```
public static class Pojo implements Comparable<Pojo> {

    Integer value;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pojo o) {
        return value.compareTo(o.value);
    }

    // getters and setter ommited

}
```

Is it ok to change `value` of a `Pojo` while it's in a `TreeSet`? I don't mind if this breaks the sorting in the `TreeSet`.

I'm curious because changing `value` used in a `hashCode()` or `equas()` while the instance is in a `HashMap` is not a good idea.

Comment: In a TreeSet either. Searching would be unreliable as in the left subtree could be greater elements etcetera.

Comment: To underline @JoopEggen's argument, [here is an Ideone demo highlighting the problem](https://ideone.com/MU8LnY).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we change attributes that influence the element order, we violate contracts of `TreeSet`.

As per [`TreeSet`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html), it

> ... provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (`add`, `remove` and `contains`).

The `TreeSet` can guarantee those time costs by keeping the set ordered. If we, however, change attributes of elements, that would in turn change the ordering within the set, we break this contract. The `TreeSet` does not constantly "*monitor*" all elements for changes. Furthermore, a change could trigger a reorder, which would have costs of `n * log(n)` (with `n` being the current size of the `TreeSet`).

We can make the effects of this form of contract violation visible with the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo fooOne = Foo.of(1);
        Foo fooTwo = Foo.of(2);
        Foo fooThree = Foo.of(3);
        TreeSet<Foo> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.addAll(List.of(fooOne, fooTwo, fooThree));
        System.out.println(set.contains(fooOne));
        fooOne.setValue(4);
        System.out.println(set.contains(fooOne));
        System.out.println(new ArrayList<>(set).contains(fooOne));
    }
}

class Foo implements Comparable<Foo> {
    private int value;

    private Foo(int value) {
        this.setValue(value);
    }

    public static Foo of(int value) {
        return new Foo(value);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Foo setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Foo foo = (Foo) o;
        return getValue() == foo.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(value);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo that) {
        return getValue() - that.getValue();
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rpLwa1)

If the `TreeSet` would reorder on element attribute changes, all three lines should show `true`. However, since we changed `fooOne`'s `value` from `1` to `4` (hence it would be expected to be the last element in the set), the second `contains(fooOne)` will return `false` since the `TreeSet` is no longer sorted. Converting the `TreeSet` into an `ArrayList` and searching within the `ArrayList`, however, yields the expected result since the `ArrayList` does not make any assumption about element order.

If the guaranteed log(n) time cost for basic operation is not essential to the use case, I would suggest using a different data structure (e.g. a `List`) that does not rely on element ordering. Keep in mind, however, that this comes at a higher time cost for (at least some of the) basic operations.

EDIT:

As was [mentioned by @Scratte in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957173/is-it-ok-to-change-a-value-that-is-used-in-compareto-in-a-treeset/63957580?noredirect=1#comment113103832_63957580), we can even break the `TreeSet` on a more fundamental level by adding the (modified, but still identical wrt. `==`) `fooOne` to the `TreeSet`, increasing its size by one:

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo fooOne = Foo.of(1);
        Foo fooTwo = Foo.of(2);
        Foo fooThree = Foo.of(3);
        TreeSet<Foo> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.addAll(List.of(fooOne, fooTwo, fooThree));
        System.out.println(set.size());
        fooOne.setValue(4);
        set.add(fooOne);
        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/eCFqwF)

Comment: The problem isn't just order and finding elements. You can add `fooOne` to your set again and increase it's size to 4, breaking the very contract of `Set`.